# dataframe bar plot not looks good

Tags: python, tkinter, plot

I'm trying to plot data with ~2000 values as bar kind, but the plot looks bad. probably because the amount of values.

In case I have 500 values, the plot looks ok.

Here is my simple code:

```
data = {
            'du': duList,
            'sum_of_avg': sum_of_avg,
            'sum_of_max': sum_of_max,
            'sum_of_std': sum_of_std
        }

df = DataFrame(data)
df.plot(x='du', y=['sum_of_avg', 'sum_of_max', 'sum_of_std'], kind='bar')
```

[image]

What I'm missing?

Comment: Do you really need to get all values in one plot? It's a lot of information for a single visualization, plus there are widely different scales making some of the data invisible (all your tiny bars): what about sorting/grouping and plotting less categories at once?

Comment: @Learningisamess I was thinking about to show in x axis in steps of 50,: 1, 50, 100...2000. but i cant find how to do it